# Adding a key/value pair at the same time as creating a sub-object

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to working with objects. I want to:

1. Add a key
2. Add a sub-object to that key
3. Push the key/value pair to this sub-object.

For example, the data structure I am looking to achieve would be:

```
invalidFields = {
    "_0" : {
        "firstName" : "foo",
        "lastName" : "la",
    }
}
```

The addition of the most nested key/value pair is done by iterating and comparing, so in essence it needs to be **added** to "_0", not overwriting it.

So far I have:

```
let invalidFields = {}; // this is initialised outside of the for loop
...
const field = "foo";
const passengerIdentifier = "_" + passengerIndex; // "_0"
const fieldKey = "firstName";
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] = field;
```

This adds the key/value pair of `"firstName": "foo"` but when the loop continues it therefore overwrites it so the data I get is only `field` applied :

```
invalidFields = {
    "_0" : "foo",
}
```

This is obviously not correct as I need the key/value pairs to add to the `"_0"` sub-object. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is an example of what I have now, but this does not seem to work, the field part isn't added:

```
const passengerIdentifier = '_'+passengerIndex;
if (!invalidFields[passengerIdentifier]) {
    Object.assign(invalidFields, { [passengerIdentifier] : '' });
    Object.assign(invalidFields[passengerIdentifier], { [fieldKey]: field });
}
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear . Do you want multiple keys '_0' in your object. This is not possible. Keys in an object are unique.

Comment: Could you please post full loop? It is hard to answer not knowing what kind of data you iterate over.

Comment: `Object.assign(invalidFields, { [passengerIdentifier] : '' });` assigns a string, but you need an object for the content.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank you! that works

Comment: @NinaScholz however it doesn't add them in any order :( is it possible to keep them in order?

Comment: objects have actually no order, but they are usually iterated by creation order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and add the new key/value to the existing object in the loop.

```
// outside of the loop
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] = {};

// inside of the loop
Object.assign(invalidFields[passengerIdentifier], { [fieldKey]: field });
```

Just for completeness, it is possible, to assign a value directly to an object

```
// inside of the loop
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier][fieldKey] = field;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem nice and succinct. However I am now struggling to use the same concept to actually add the first part `passengerIdentifier` e.g `_0` in the same way. Could you provide an example all the way from the initialisation of `invalidFields = {}` ?

Answer (score 2):

To add key/value pair to each sub-object use the following approach:

```
...
var field = "foo",
    passengerIdentifier = "_" + passengerIndex, // "_0"
    fieldKey = "firstName";

// assuring sub-object with certain `passengerIdentifier`
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] = invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] || {};
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier][fieldKey] = field;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let invalidFields = {}; // this is initialised outside of the for loop
    ...
    const field = "foo";
    const passengerIdentifier = "_" + passengerIndex; // "_0"
    const fieldKey = "firstName";

    var subObject = {
         'key1' : value1,
         'key2' : value2,
         // add all keys
     }

    invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] = subObject ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're trying to achieve?

```
invalidFields[passengerIdentifier] = { 
  [fieldKey]: field 
}
```